# Android intent filter not able to find the correct match to my universal link with pathPrefix / pathPattern

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, deep-linking

I am trying to make my react-native application open on Android only when it hits a link like this:
`https://example.co/something/reset-password?key=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MDIyNzEwMjYsInR5cGUiOiJ1c2VycyIsInV1aWQiOiIzYmVhMDM2Ni01MmE4LTU2YTgtYWQ2OS1iNjlhM2VlMmMxNWEifQ.urvZ41ivWPJRl_LtyLXtSqSHzaE5XdClxSvJC9AL-vI`

Where `something` can change. And the token as well.

What I tried and didn't work:

`<data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.co" android:pathPattern="/.*/reset-password?key=.*"/>`

`<data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.co" android:pathPattern="/.*/reset-password\?key=.*"/>`

`<data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.co" android:pathPattern="/.*/reset-password\\?key=.*"/>`

`<data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.co" android:pathPattern="/.*/reset-password\\\?key=.*"/>`

`<data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.co" android:pathPrefix="/.*/reset-password" />`

I have only managed to be able to open the app with that link using this
`<data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.co" />`
but it's not what we want.